# Using bash, read each line from file and write it to a variable delimited by comma

Tags: bash

I am trying to read a text file which contains the following sample values:

```
Apple
Banana
Carrot
```

...I will then need write them to a variable as a single line delimited by comma.

```
var1=Apple,Banana,Carrot
```

How does one do it using bash script? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: Reading the lines into a comma-delimited variable is a weird thing to want. Probably a better idea - depending on the use case, of course - is to read them into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -rn 's/\n/;/g;s/^/var1=/p' file
```

Consume the file as one line (-z). Substitute every newline for ";" and then replace the start of the line with "var1="